# request response iso8583 message of passbook / ATM machine (kiosk)

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, banking, iso8583

we have banking project in .net. in that project we need to implement passbook printing.

 
-Passbook will have magnetic stripe on rear side of passbook.

 
-When customer inserts passbook into kiosk, kiosk will generate **ISO 8583** message.

 
-In response to this message CBS(project) will send customer details such as customer name, address etc.

 
-Bank will provide A central server having OS as Windows Server 2008 / 2012 , 64 bit.

 
- Aplab will provide Central Server software.

 
- All kiosks will connect to this central server software.

 
-Central server software will connect to bank CBS(project). It means there will be only one channel between CBS and all kiosk's.

 
-Bank has to open two ports, one from Central server to CBS and another from kiosk to central server.

this info sent by bank

this is new module i need to develope. i have no idea about this. never did this kind of developement. i studied iso 8583 standards. and now planning to use Trx framework.
please suggest me if there is any other good framework. and how will be the flow of this module. where should i start.

contribute your knowledge to help me. 
see the image 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just module of implementing passbook printing (and need not worry about the Infrastructure) then 
you can start off with the overview as described below

- you just have to handle the packets coming from kiosk in Middle server
- Forward them to CBS server
- Handle them and form the particular response and send back in a way kiosk understand.

I think ATM mini statement requests are sent in 0200 message with request information in processing code. According to the specification of a switch used by a bank, we need to form the message packet.

If central server is dedicated for the particular module, then you need a way to communicate to your CBS server application.

And as far the trx framework is concerned, It's well known framework fits well if it's a .NET project.